# Is it possible to access a property value from another maven project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, properties-file

I have a SpringBoot service:

```
package test;

@Service
public class TestService {

  @Value("${service.readTimeout}")
  private Duration readTimeout;
}
```

`service.readTimeout` is not declared in my current project's property files. **It is linked in a separate project, which are all marked as Maven modules.**

How is the value from the other property file being accessed by this project ?

The project is **not listed as a dependency** or mentioned in the `pom.xml` for the project that is using the value.

**Does Maven connect all declared modules ? Are all files accessible from all projects ?**

What is going on here ?

Comment: Where is service.readTimeout configured?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli In a different project. All projects are marked as modules in the `pom.xml`. They are all sub modules under a main project. Does that answer your question ?

Answer (score 1):

To get an external ressource you can use `FileSystemResource`, for example I have two projects `demo` and `demo2` :

[image]

So I want to have access to `demo` **application.properties** from `demo2`,so you can use this code :

```
Resource resource = new FileSystemResource("absolute path");
// for example : C:\\Users\\Developper\\eclipse workspace\\demo\\src\\main\\resources\\application.properties

Properties props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
System.out.println(props);
```

**If you are forced to use annotations**, you can try : `@PropertySource("file:/path/to/propertiesfile")` : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html

Comment: Yes but this is not used in my project. No extra code for this is there.

Comment: you are obliged to use annotations ?

Comment: You can use @PropertySource("file:/path/to/propertiesfile") : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html

Comment: You might want to add this into the answer.